# can i redirect user to other jsp page in shiro jdbcrealm doGetAuthenticationInfo() method?

Tags: java, jsp, shiro

Hello all I want to know can I redirect user to accessdeniedpage.jsp in shiro custom jdbcrealm
Here is my code....

```
  protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws HostUnauthorizedException,AuthenticationException {

    UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) token;
    String username = upToken.getUsername();
    String clientIP = upToken.getHost();

    // Null username is invalid
    if (username == null) {
        throw new AccountException("Null usernames are not allowed by this realm.");
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    AuthenticationInfo info = null;
    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();

        String password = getPasswordForUser(conn, username); // get userpassword
        boolean ipFlag = getIPFlag(conn,username); // check whether users ip needs to be check i.e. get ipflag from users tbl, if true check user's ip else not
        boolean ipMatched = checkIP(conn,username,clientIP,ipFlag); // returns if user's ip matched with ip stored in database..

        if (password == null) {
            throw new UnknownAccountException("No account found for user [" + username + "]");
        }

        if(ipMatched == false){
             // how to redirect user to accessdeniedpage.jsp ?
        }

        info = buildAuthenticationInfo(username, password.toCharArray());

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        final String message = "There was a SQL error while authenticating user [" + username + "]";
        if (log.isErrorEnabled()) {
            log.error(message, e);
        }

        // Rethrow any SQL errors as an authentication exception
        throw new AuthenticationException(message, e);
    } finally {
        JdbcUtils.closeConnection(conn);
    }

    return info;
}
```

I am checking users ip, if ip not found in database I want to redirect user to accessdenied page

Update `shiro.ini`

```
 [main]
ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.requiredType   = javax.sql.DataSource
ds.resourceName = jdbc/myDataSource
ds.resourceRef = true
jdbcRealm = com.java.realm.MyRealm 

# password hashing specification
sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher

jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true 
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ? 
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role_name FROM user_roles WHERE username = ? 
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT roleper FROM roles_permissions WHERE role_name = ? 
jdbcRealm.permissionsQueryIP = SELECT ip FROM user_ip_permissions WHERE username = ? 
jdbcRealm.permissionsQueryCountry = SELECT countryname FROM country_permissions WHERE username = ? 
jdbcRealm.defaultPageQuery = SELECT default_page FROM users WHERE username = ?


jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
jdbcRealm.authorizationCachingEnabled = false

# specify login page 
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp 

# redirect after successful login
authc.successUrl = /home.jsp

# roles filter: redirect to error page if user does not have access rights
# perms filter: redirect to error page if user does not have permissions
roles.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.jsp
perms.unauthorizedUrl = /accessdenied.jsp


# request parameter with login error information; if not present filter assumes 'shiroLoginFailure'
# authc.failureKeyAttribute = simpleShiroApplicationLoginFailure


[urls] 


/login.jsp = authc

# only users with some roles are allowed to use role-specific pages 
/admin/** = authc,perms[page:*]
/java/** = authc,perms[page:javadeveloperpage]
/php/** = authc,perms[page:phpdeveloperpage]
/ruby/** = authc,perms[page:rubydeveloperpage]
/deo/** = authc,perms[page:deopage]

# enable authc filter for all application pages
/ApacheShiroLogin/** = authc
```

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to deny access, logically you need to to throw `AuthorizationException` and map it to your custom page in `web.xml`

```
if(ipMatched == false){
    throw new AuthorizationException();
}
```

And in your **web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationException</exception-type>
    <location>/path/to/accessdeniedpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

On a side note, throwing `AuthenticationException` would be *logical* only in case of **authentication failures**.

Comment: thanks for help but it redirecting me to login.jsp page again